# Appending data to an indexed table

Tags: ms-access, indexing, vba, append, autonumber

I'm attempting to append records to a table that has data indexed by an ID column.  I'd like the appended data to continue that indexing and attach the next number to the first appended record and so on.  However, that ID column is not an AutoNumber column--the first number needed to be 5001 so it's current Data Type is "Number".  The data already in that table is entered via a form with this VBA to format the ID column:

```
    If Nz(Me.ID, "") = "" Then
    NewID = Int(DMax("ID", "tComplianceAll") + 1)
Else
    NewID = Me.ID
End If
```

I currently have an append query to try to append the new data to the table with this SQL for that ID column : Int(DMax("ID","tComplianceAll")+1) AS Expr1

That, however, only works for the first record.  The rest do not get appended due to key violations since it's trying to assign the same ID number for all appended records.  Is there a way to change that SQL so that it properly indexes the newly appended data?

Comment: You can "seed" the starting value of an autonumber field, and that is by far the easiest route to solving your problem, use an Autonumber. As long as your current data is sound I believe you can still change the data type.

Comment: Another option, if you don't want to define an autonumber column, is to write a bit of VBA code to append the data.

Answer (score 0):

You surely can use a standard Autonumber ID value here!

1. Edit table `tComplianceAll` and change the `ID` column type to `AutoNumber`
2. Then, set the next value using this SQL:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE tComplianceAll ALTER COLUMN ID AUTOINCREMENT(5001,1)
   ```

   Actually, you would change `5001` to the latest value returned by  `(DMax("ID", "tComplianceAll") + 1)`

That should do it, providing that `tComplianceAll` is not in any relationships with other foreign tables using the `ID` field.